# How do I rename all secrets in an Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I need to add a prefix to all my secrets in an Azure Key Vault.

There seems to be no API or cmdlet for this, and not possible in the Azure Portal either.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a example is Bash.

```sh
AZURE_KEY_VAULT_NAME=<Your KeyVault name>
PREFIX="-old"

for secret_name in $(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $AZURE_KEY_VAULT_NAME --query '[].[name]' -o tsv); do
  echo "Rename ${secret_name} into ${secret_name}${PREFIX}"
  secret=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name $AZURE_KEY_VAULT_NAME --name ${secret_name} --query value -o tsv)
  az keyvault secret set --vault-name $AZURE_KEY_VAULT_NAME --name ${secret_name}${PREFIX} --value $secret
  # Delete original key if needed
  # az keyvault secret delete --vault-name $AZURE_KEY_VAULT_NAME --name ${secret_name}
  # Perminantly
  # az keyvault secret purge  --vault-name $AZURE_KEY_VAULT_NAME --name ${secret_name}
done
```

Instead of list over all keys, you could use `grep` to get a subset, or just provide a list (space seperated) of secrets, e.g.

- `$(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $AZURE_KEY_VAULT_NAME --query '[].[name]' -o tsv | grep example)`
- `secret1 secret2 secret3`

Answer (score 5):

The PowerShell script below creates new keys with a prefix added.

```
(az keyvault secret list --vault-name <AZURE_KEY_VAULT_NAME> | ConvertFrom-Json) | %{ az keyvault secret show --id $_.id | ConvertFrom-Json | %{ az keyvault secret set --vault-name ([uri]$_.id).Host.Split('.')[0] -n "<PREFIX>-$(([uri]$_.id).Segments[2].TrimEnd('/'))" --value `"$($_.value)`" } }
```

Make sure to replace `<AZURE_KEY_VAULT_NAME>` and `<PREFIX>` before running the script.

The `az` PowerShell module can be installed from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/

Comment: what sort of monstrosity is that?