# How to Override Web.config values with Azure KeyVault in .NET Framework 4.7.1

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, azure-keyvault, .net-4.7.1

How can I implement Microsoft's Azure KeyVault in a ASP.NET Framework 4.7.1 WebForms application to override values in `web.config` with values from KeyVault? I do see references that we need a minimum version of .NET Framework 4.7.1 in order to do it but the examples Microsoft provides are for .NET Core. I have my configs as `web.config` files instead of `appsettings.json`. I also have `Global.asax.cs` files instead of `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs`.

Answer (score 8):

To  implement Microsoft's Azure KeyVault in a ASP.NET Framework 4.7.1 WebForms application  , first you need to create an Azure Key Vault.

- You need to provide a resource group, unique name and location ,then
  click on Review + Create.
- Can refer Steps to create Azure keyvault
  here>>(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-portal)
- Next select the Secrets blade and add your app settings and
  connection strings that can be accessed in web.config file . You can
  click on the Generate/Import button and choose the Upload options as
  Manual. Then configure your app settings and connection strings -
  keys and values to the Name and Value options. And keep other options
  as default.

> *Configuration builders in ASP.NET provide a way to modify and/or override the values coming from your configuration files (Web.config
> in the case of ASP.NET) by using different sources (environment
> variables, Key Vault, etc.).*

**Connecting to Azure Key Vault:**

- To connect to Azure Key Vault from Visual Studio, you need to right
  click on the project and select Add > Connected Service menu.
  [image]
- From the options, choose Secure Secrets with Azure Key Vault option.

[image]

- Now you may need to sign in if not already signed in to your account
  and then select  rquired key vault  from the list.
  [image]
- And click on the Add button to add key vault reference to your
  application. This will add reference of the NuGet package
  Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure to the project.

Also it will add some configuration in the Web.Config file.

(OR)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click on your project, and select Manage
  NuGet Packages. In the Browse tab, locate and install
  Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure

Open your **web.config** file, and write the following code:

a) Add configSections and configBuilders as below with your  keyvault name

```xml
     <configSections>
        <section
            name="configBuilders"
            type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
            restartOnExternalChanges="false"
            requirePermission="false" />
     </configSections>
     <configBuilders>
        <builders>
        <add
                name="AzureKeyVault"
                vaultName="vaultname"
                type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"
                vaultUri="https://vaultname.vault.azure.net" />
        </builders>
     </configBuilders>
```

b) Find the appSettings tag, add an attribute configBuilders="AzureKeyVault", and add a line     as below:

```xml
    <appSettings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
      <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
      <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="TextAnalyticsKey" value="from key vault" />
    </appSettings>

    <connectionStrings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="from key vault" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="from key vault" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

c) Edit the About method in HomeController.cs, to display the value for confirmation.

```cs
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Key vault value = " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TextAnalyticsKey"];
    }
```

This way you can connect and use Azure Key Vault in your classic ASP.NET MVC applications,if you’re application  running is using .NET Framework 4.7 or later versions.

**You can refer following documents for the detailed explaination of the same :**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service#added-references-for-aspnet-framework
- https://dotnetthoughts.net/azure-key-vault-in-aspnet-mvc/   helps you how to connect and use Azure Key Vault in your ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the information. However how will getting config setting from keyvault work when key name in `web.config` has a '.' character? Like so: `<add key="DB.StorageConnectionString" value="from key vault" />`. KeyVault does not support the period character so I have replaced with a dash character. Is there a way to transform the secret name coming from KeyVault so that it matches what is in `web.config`?

Comment: Refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59098513/how-do-i-rename-all-secrets-in-an-azure-key-vault  >Is this  question similar to what you asked?

Comment: Hi. I don't need to rename them in KeyVault. Need to rename them after I've fetched the secrets. I basically need an equivalent of the `KeyVaultSecretManager` like shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-a-key-name-prefix

. Difference is, I need option to not pass a prefix and instead of `appsettings.json` I have a `web.config` file.

Comment: So say in keyvault i have a secret named `DB-StorageConnectionString`. When I load that secret, i need the name transformed to `DB.StorageConnectionString` so that the key in my config file is found.

Comment: you may want to take a look at this >>https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/integrating-azure-key-vaults-with-classic-asp-net-applications/

Comment: Thanks for the article. I may have missed it but where in the attached link does it show me to rename the secret as I have stated previously?

Comment: @Bmoe: I only heard Azure Key Vault can't use colon as a separator  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-an-array-to-a-class), but I didn't know you can't use the dot. Where did you get that information?

Comment: By default Azure.Identity 1.1.1 is installed, which does not support Visual Studio Credential. You can update package reference manually to 1.2+ use Visual Studio Credential.
Also, this line should be manually modified: 
<appSettings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">