# How to change Key Vault Account in Visual Studio as a Connected service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-keyvault

I have succesfully connected an ASP.NET (.Net Framework 4.7.2) web application to a demo Azure Key Vault using a "quick" set up using the following links:

[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68089561/how-to-override-web-config-values-with-azure-keyvault-in-net-framework-4-7-1)

[Microsoft Docementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service#access-your-secrets-aspnet)

I can even read the secrets using the web.config file. But now, after testing the application, I need to change the azure suscription and the key vault accordingly to deploy the final version.

How I do this with ASP.NET? (I have found a lot of documentation supporting ASP.NET Core, but not ASP.NET).

When I open the Azure Key vault page in the "connected services" pane of the Deployment tab, I get a page like this:

[image]

But is the red highlighted area in the picture above, the links take me to the azure key vault web page. So, there is not a configuration page within Visual Studio to change the azure suscription and key vault. In the application there is only a reference to the key vault in the Web.Config file. The connectedService.json file does not contain any useful information either.

I need to read the secrets from the web.config and not from anyther place. I have even written a method to read the secrets overriding the web.config. But this not aceptable, since the application architecture reads all the connections from the web.config file

Any ideas, please?.

Comment: Is this link useful? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aee86abd-9152-4ea4-88ab-565bd91191bf/how-can-i-use-azure-key-vault-with-vs-2017-and-web-forms-app?forum=aspdotnetazure

Comment: Thank you, but not. It's similar to the other links I posted. It only tells you how to assign a key vault the first time, but it doesn't tell you how to change the suscription nor the key vault for that suscription.

Comment: And there is another link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-connected-services-app-configuration?view=vs-2022

But it's the same situation.

Comment: HI @Rick_Barb , Are you trying to change the existing key vault subscription in your application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Work around

You can access different  subscription for any of your accounts directly

**1)** **Server Explorer by right-clicking on the Azure node**, choosing **Manage and Filter Subscriptions**,
[image]

**2)** You get the list all subscription select the subscription. and select the subscription for your application

[image]

To Move the key vault to another subscription refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/move-subscription#moving-key-vault-to-a-new-subscription-within-the-same-tenant):

Comment: Thank you. With this approach, I can assign another suscription. This answers my question.