Saving smtp password from web.config to Azure key vault
I am running an ASP.NET application. I have moved the connection strings and some app settings from web.config to Azure key vault secrets.
But I can't figure out how to read the SMTP server password from Azure key vault as well since it is not a key/value setting like the connection strings and app settings.
Does anybody know if it is possible?
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="kundeservice@xxx.xxx" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <network host="smtp.office365.com" port="587" userName="xxx@xxx.com" password="[SET PASSWORD FROM KEYVAULT]" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>


Can you please share the screenshot of how you have set smtp  password in Azure keyvault

Check if this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/68100828/4317508

@YuQing Zhang - Are you still looking for sol?
